Problems setting up a simple RaspberryPi IRS in C++ using pigpio library
I want to make a simple Interrupt Service Routine on my RaspberryPi4 using the pigpio library
This is my simple setup:
Setup
And Here is my simple code:
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <pigpio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

void sayHello(int gpio, int level, uint32_t tick)
{
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Initialize pigpio library
    if (gpioInitialise() < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to initialize GPIO" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Set GPIO pin mode
    if (gpioSetMode(16, PI_INPUT) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to set GPIO mode" << std::endl;
        gpioTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Set ISR function
    int result = gpioSetISRFunc(16, RISING_EDGE, 0, sayHello);
    if (result < 0) {
        std::cerr << "ISR setup fail - error code: " << result << std::endl;
        gpioTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // Wait for input
    int exit;
    std::cin >> exit;

    // Clean up and terminate pigpio library
    gpioTerminate();
    return 0;
}


When i run this, i get two or three types of errors, depending on my pigpio daemon setup on the pi.
1) No daemon running before launching program
NoDae
Here I'm able to run the gpio library. I can gpioInitialize and set input/outputs. Run PWM ect.
The problems comes when i try to setup the ISR.
// Set ISR function
    int result = gpioSetISRFunc(16, RISING_EDGE, 0, sayHello);
    if (result < 0) {
        std::cerr << "ISR setup fail - error code: " << result << std::endl;
        gpioTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

This gives me the output "ISR setup fail - error code: -123".
2) Daemon running before launching program
I tried starting the daemon outside. I've read that in normal cases it's running on the RaspberryPi all the time, and then the program will use the existing daemon to access/modify the gpio on the RaspberryPi.
But when i started it (sudo pigpiod):
Dae
The gpioInitialize fails and I get the error message: pigpio Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid
My theory is that the program is trying to create another daemon instead of using the existing one, but I'm not sure. Many threads/videos i've seen says that I should kill the existing the daemons. But then I'm back to problem 1).
3) Port issues when deleting /var/run/pigpio.pid
The issue 2) was around the file /var/run/pigpio.pid. I tried deleting it in order to not have any conflicts with it, but that raised another problem with the port being in use already:
PortP
But to be honest, i doubt thats the issue i should look at.

I hope someone can help me. Surely I'm not the only one who've ran into this problem setting up a simple interrupt routine with the pigpio library, which should be one of the most updated and used libraries to control the Raspberry Pi's I/O
Thanks in advance!
1)
I've looked into this: Thread, discusses that the ports are being occupied. But i've tried so many different gpio ports (23, 24, 17, 16) and none of them works. So i dont believe thats the issue.
I read somewhere, that the error code usually means the pigpio hasn't started correctly. But as far as i know the program will start the daemon if one doesnt already exist. Anything else would also seem strange to me since the rest of the gpio seems to work, except for the interrupt setups.

& 3)
I've tried to reinstall gpio, updated to the newest version.

PS.
I always run the program as sudo.

Make sure you go through pigpio C Interface and see the Examples link in the left column. As you found, you can either run pigpio with sockets or as a daemon. The library is well-written, but a bit cumbersome to use (and requires programs to be run as root). If you look closely in the Examples link you will find a tinyGPIO library that offers an alternative using /dev/gpiomem. It is a simple mapping of the gpio memory provided for that purpose. Much lighter on the Pi than the full daemon.

Thanks for the response! I looked into the tinyGPIO library. But as far as I can see it doesn't handle Interrupt Service Routines? This is the whole dilemma, since I want an IRS to run when I press the microswitch. The program is running the daemon right now, and that's completely fine by me. But somehow the program fails to put up the IRS. Can it be the way I compile the program with cmake? Do I need to include something in my cmakelist.txt? Perhabs i should use gpioSetAlertFunc() instead of gpioSetIRSFunc,, I  dont really understand the difference between these.

The gpioSetAlertFunc seems to work. Unlike the gpioSetIRSFunc it doesn't give me the -123 error code

I've grown a bit leery of using other libraries. For most interrupts I simply use sigaction to set a signal handler and for creating timers use create_timer which are wonderful for creating interval timers.  That avoids all of the changing libraries that Pi has gone through in the past few years. Here is a good link for gpiod The new GPIO Interface on the Raspberry PI

I'm having exactly the same issue on a PI 1B. When I run the code on my PI 4 it works without any problems! So I think that pigpio ISR are not supported on the old PIs!?! Anyways, I "solved" the problem by manually reading the value of the pin on a regular time interval
